# How to publish a library to npm that can be used both with import and require?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babeljs, es6-modules

[tealium-tracker](https://github.com/moroshko/tealium-tracker) is written in es6 and transpiled using Babel before published to npm.

When consumers do:

```js
import initTealiumTracker from "tealium-tracker";
```

everything works as expected.

However, some consumers want to use a `require` instead of an `import`, and have to append `.default`:

```js
const initTealiumTracker = require("tealium-tracker).default;
```

How could I publish the library to avoid appending `.default`?

I want consumers to be able to do either:

```js
import initTealiumTracker from "tealium-tracker";
```

or

```js
const initTealiumTracker = require("tealium-tracker);
```

[Source code](https://github.com/moroshko/tealium-tracker)

Comment: write your code using modern `import`/`export` syntax, then have a build step that generates a `/dist/yourlib.js` using that modern syntax, and a `/dist/yourlib.legacy.js` and tell people that if you use old versions of Node they should require the legacy version in the README.md?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your source code, If you are ok with using commonJS syntax for import and export...

One option would be to replace all `import` and `export` with `require` and `module.exports`. Looks like webpack doesn't allow mixing the syntaxes (ES6 and commonJS modules).

So your `index.js` file can `require` the functions from dependent module as

```
const { callUtag, flushUtagQueue } = require("./utagCaller");
```

and export the default function as

```
module.exports = initTealiumTracker;
module.exports.default = initTealiumTracker;
```

Likewise your dependent module can export the functions as

```
module.exports = { callUtag, flushUtagQueue };
```

This way, consumers should be able to use either

```
import initTealiumTracker2 from "tealium-tracker";
```

**OR**

```
const initTealiumTracker1 = require("tealium-tracker");
```